# Clash in the Clouds: Can money be used for anything?

Tags: bioshock-infinite, bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds

I've completed every level (although not gotten every Blue Ribbon). Bought every Vigor and Weapon upgrade from both Vending Machines. Purchased every item in the Museum. And yet I still collect cash for completing levels.

[image]

Aside from purchasing Resurrections, is there anywhere else in the game I can use this money?

Comment: Is this specifically about the DLC or the game in general?

Comment: @Batophobia What are you referring to?

Comment: For general game, money can be spent on things like [health kits, salts, lockpicks, and ammo](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Dollar_Bill).  For specific DLC, I'm not sure since I haven't played it.

Comment: @Batophobia Since the OP tagged the question as expansion-specific, you can safely assume that he meant money in the DLC not in the game in general.

Comment: @Batophobia "Clash in the Clouds" is the name of the DLC for Bioshock Infinite. There are no "Dollar Bill" vending machines in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have purchased all the things you have mentioned, then you are done "unlocking things" in the DLC. There are no additional unlockables.

http://www.gamefront.com/bioshock-infinite-clash-in-the-clouds-museum-unlockables-list/ - Once you have all of these, then you have unlocked everything.

Comment: Cool, but aside from unlockables, what else can this mounting pile of cash be used for? :)

Comment: Weapons, upgrades, and so forth. Empty all the vendors of things you can buy, and anything else would just be ammo and basic reusable things.